# Array to other array,autocomplete

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax

How can I manage to be good this array to this function:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var availableTags=getAllUserIdName();
    $( "#members" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags 
    });
};

function getAllUserIdName(){
    $.get('{{url('/')}}/ajax-all-user-id-name',function(data){
        return data;
    });
}
```

I got this response back:

```
[{"name":"asd"},{"name":"qwqe"},{"name":"gipsz jakab"}]
```

Thx!

Comment: I think you miss the parameter in your function. See here: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#folding

Answer (score 0):

```js
var testData = [
  {"name":"asd"},{"name":"qwqe"},{"name":"gipsz jakab"}
];

getAllUserIdName(function(tags){
  $("#members").autocomplete({ source: tags });
});
    
function getAllUserIdName(callback){
    // simulate asynchronous request for data:
    setTimeout(function(){
        var data = testData;
        var tags = data.map(function(item){ return item.name; });
        callback(tags);
    }, 300);
      
    /*$.get('{{url('/')}}/ajax-all-user-id-name',function(data){
        var tags = data.map(function(item) { return item.name; }); 
        callback(tags);
    });*/
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <label for="members">Members: </label>
  <input id="members">
```